# Convert polygon to triangles

Tags: c, opengl, geometry, polygon

In order to create a VBO in OpenGl, I need to convert polygons to triangles.
Is there an example of script/code somewhere that would describe this ?
I would need something robust for convex and concave polygons.

Comment: I untagged this [cocoa] and tagged it [c] because I don't think it's a Cocoa question (or even an Objective-C question).

Comment: for those of you who need an implementation and not a pdf or description: https://github.com/mapbox/earcut

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Ear clipping](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf) is by far the best way to do this.

It is fully robust for both convex and concave polygons and runs in O(n^2) time

Comment: This one worked like a charm and is easy, thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Implement [Chazelle's method](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/polygon-triang.pdf).  Triangulation in linear time!  What's not to like? :)

More realistically, [poly2tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/).

Answer (score 0):

GLU tesselators provide a flexible way to do this.

Comment: GLU tesselators are deprecated.